# cross ref between \frametitles{} in latex

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

I have a long beamer presentation so I would like to create an unnumerated reference to `\frametitle` in both directions. Many thanks in advance.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Sample title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{Overleaf}
\date{2021}

\begin{document}
    
    \frame{\titlepage}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Sample frame title} 
        FIRST TEXT REF TO -> frametitle{APPENDIX}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Sample frame title}
    SECOND TEXT
\end{frame}


\appendix

\section{Appendix Bibliometric Dataset of Chapter 2}

\begin{frame}   \frametitle{APPENDIX} 
    APPENDIX REF TO -> frametitle{Sample frame title}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give your frame a label, you can use `\hyperlink{label}{some text}` to jump between them:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Sample title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{Overleaf}
\date{2021}

\begin{document}
    
    \frame{\titlepage}
    
    \begin{frame}[label=firstframe]
        \frametitle{Sample frame title} 
        \hyperlink{appendixframe}{\beamergotobutton{Appendix}}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Sample frame title}
    SECOND TEXT
\end{frame}


\appendix

\section{Appendix Bibliometric Dataset of Chapter 2}

\begin{frame}[label=appendixframe]
   \frametitle{APPENDIX} 
    \hyperlink{firstframe}{\beamergotobutton{back}}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]